# wurfl on elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have setup php environment on elastic beanstalk and uploading code through eb deploy command. EC2 instance is created by auto-scaling group and I can connect it using putty. I want to install wurfl on ec2, I want to know : 
1) if I install wurfl on current running ec2 instance, will it get installed on other instance created by auto-scale group ?
2) if not, then how can I install wurfl on beanstalk

Answer (score 0):

1. No, do not modify your Elastic Beanstalk instances manually. It will not replicate to another (existing/new) instances.
2. If you want to customize your instances, you can create `.ebextensions` scripts. Please take a look into http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html.

Comment: thanks Edward, got the simpler way to customise software stack on beanstalk http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.customenv.html :)